# Link in breadcrumbs becomes bigger

Tags: html, css

On page buhuchet.html the link in breadcrumbs "Главная страница"(Mainpage) becomes bigger than on page denis-shevchuk-buhuchet-nalogooblozhenie-upravlencheskiy-uchet-samouchitel.html

Can't understand why.
Please help.

**buhuchet.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Книги по бухучету</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
    <style type="text/css">
      a:link { 
        font-size: 24px; /* Размер шрифта*/
        font-weight: none; /* Жирное начертание */
        color: red; /* Цвет ссылки */ 
      }
      a:visited { 
        font-size: none ; /* Размер шрифта*/
        font-weight: none; /* Жирное начертание */
        color: none; /* Цвет ссылки */ 
      }
      a:active: { 
        font-size: none ; /* Размер шрифта*/
        font-weight: none; /* Жирное начертание */
        color: none; /* Цвет ссылки */ 
      }
      a:hover { 
        font-size: none ; /* Размер шрифта*/
        font-weight: none; /* Жирное начертание */
        color: none; /* Цвет ссылки */ 
      }
 
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
p {
    margin: 0;
}
img {
    display: block;
}
 
.center-img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
    </style>   
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
      <li><a href="../index.html" target="_blank">Главная страница</a></li>
      <li>Бухучет</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Люди, которые ищут книги по бухучету, также могут интересоваться: </p>
    <p><a href="https://unive.com.ru" target="_blank">Здесь будет картинка</a> 
    <h1 align="center">Книги по бухучету</h1>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>          
            <p><img src="images/book covers/178219-denis-shevchuk-buhuchet-nalogooblozhenie-upravlencheskiy-uchet-samouchitel.jpg" width="75%" alt="Денис Шевчук. Бухучет, налогообложение, управленческий учет: самоучитель" class="center-img"></p>
          </td>
          <td>
        <p><a href="books/denis-shevchuk-buhuchet-nalogooblozhenie-upravlencheskiy-uchet-samouchitel.html" target="_blank">Денис Шевчук. Бухучет, налогообложение, управленческий учет: самоучитель</a></p>
            <p><img src="images/noun_Online feedback_2019640 colored.png" width="10%" alt="Хороший рейтинг"></p> 
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p><img src="images/book covers/6037456-pavel-smirnov-buhuchet.jpg" width="75%" alt="Бухучет" class="center-img"></p>    
      </td>
      <td>
        <p><a href="books/pavel-smirnov-buhuchet.html" target="_blank">Бухучет</a></p>
            <p><img src="images/noun_Online feedback_2019640 colored.png" width="10%" alt="Хороший рейтинг"></p>
      </td>
    </tr>           
        <tr>
      <td>
        <p><img src="images/book covers/54073841-sofya-andreevna-mironova-buhuchet-eto-prosto.jpg" width="75%" alt="Бухучет - это просто" class="center-img"></p>   
      </td>
      <td>
        <p><a href="books/sofya-andreevna-mironova-buhuchet-eto-prosto.html" target="_blank">Бухучет - это просто</p>
        <p><img src="images/noun_Online feedback_2019640 colored.png" width="10%" alt="Хороший рейтинг"></p>
          </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p><img src="images/book covers/421232-andrey-krukov-buhgalterskiy-uchet-s-nulya.jpg" width="75%" alt="Бухгалтерский учет с нуля" class="center-img"></p>     
      </td>
      <td>
        <p><a href="books/andrey-krukov-buhgalterskiy-uchet-s-nulya.html" target="_blank">Бухгалтерский учет в нуля</p>
        <p><img src="images/noun_Online feedback_2019640 colored.png" width="10%" alt="Хороший рейтинг"></p>
          </td>     
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>
        <p><img src="images/book covers/6059056-andrey-gartvich-buhgalterskiy-uchet-s-nulya-samouchitel-6059056.jpg" width="75%" alt="Бухгалтерский учет с нуля. Самоучитель" width="75%" class="center-img"></p>
          </td>
          <td>
        <p><a href="books/andrey-gartvich-buhgalterskiy-uchet-s-nulya-samouchitel.html" target="_blank">Бухгалтерский учет с нуля. Самоучитель</p>
        <p><img src="images/noun_Online feedback_2019640 colored.png" width="10%" alt="Хороший рейтинг"></p>
          </td>
    </tr>     
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p><img src="images/book covers/3936135-lubov-minaeva-vse-o-schetah-buhgalterskogo-ucheta-2-e-izdanie.jpg" width="75%" alt="Всё о счетах бухгалтерского учета (2-е издание)" class="center-img"></p>   
      </td>
      <td>
        <p><a href="books/lubov-minaeva-vse-o-schetah-buhgalterskogo-ucheta-2-e-izdanie" target="_blank">Всё о счетах бухгалтерского учета (2-е издание)</p>   
        <p><img src="images/noun_Online feedback_2019640 colored.png" width="10%" alt="Хороший рейтинг"></p>
          </td>
    </tr> 
        <tr>
      <td>
        <p><img src="images/book covers/432762-inessa-sholudchenko-angliyskiy-yazyk-buhuchet-i-audit-uchebnoe-posobie.jpg" width="75%" alt="Английский язык. Бухучет и аудит. Учебное пособие" class="center-img"></p>     
      </td>
      <td>
        <p><a href="https://www.litres.ru/inessa-sholudchenko/angliyskiy-yazyk-buhuchet-i-audit-uchebnoe-posobie/?lfrom=283042441" target="_blank">Английский язык. Бухучет и аудит. Учебное пособие</p>
        <p><img src="images/noun_Online feedback_2019640 colored.png" width="10%" alt="Хороший рейтинг"></p>
          </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p><img src="images/book covers/12490926-tamara-belikova-balans-dlya-nachinauschih-12490926.jpg" width="75%" alt="Баланс для начинающих" class="center-img"></p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p><a href="books/tamara-belikova-balans-dlya-nachinauschih.html" target="_blank">Баланс для начинающих</p>
        <p><img src="images/noun_Online feedback_2019640 colored.png" width="10%" alt="Хороший рейтинг"></p>
          </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>  
        <p><img src="images/book covers/155380-teodor-drayzer-geniy.jpg" width="75%" alt="Гений" class="center-img"></p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p><a href="books/teodor-drayzer-geniy.html" target="_blank">Гений</p>   
        <p><img src="images/noun_Online feedback_2019640 colored.png" width="10%" alt="Хороший рейтинг"></p>
          </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p><img src="images/book covers/6310613-aleksey-gerasimenko-finansovaya-otchetnost-dlya-rukovoditeley-i-nachinauschih-spe******tov-6310613.jpg" width="75%" alt="Финансовая отчетность для руководителей и начинающих специалистов" class="center-img"></p>  
      </td>
      <td>
        <p><a href="books/aleksey-gerasimenko-finansovaya-otchetnost-dlya-rukovoditeley-i-nachinauschih-spe******tov.html" target="_blank">Финансовая отчетность для руководителей и начинающих специалистов</p>
        <p><img src="images/noun_Online feedback_2019640 colored.png" width="10%" alt="Хороший рейтинг"></p>
          </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p><img src="images/book covers/6677640-elena-efremova-slovar-buhgaltera.jpg" width="75%" alt="Словарь бухгалтера" class="center-img"></p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p><a href="books/elena-efremova-slovar-buhgaltera.html" target="_blank">Словарь бухгалтера</p>
        <p><img src="images/noun_Online feedback_2019640 colored.png" width="10%" alt="Хороший рейтинг"></p>
          </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p><img src="images/book covers/179683-raznoe-teoriya-buhgalterskogo-ucheta-konspekt-lekciy.jpg" width="75%" alt="Теория бухгалтерского учета: конспект лекций" class="center-img"></p>  
      </td>
      <td>
        <p><a href="books/raznoe-teoriya-buhgalterskogo-ucheta-konspekt-lekciy.html" target="_blank">Теория бухгалтерского учета: конспект лекций</p>
        <p><img src="images/noun_Online feedback_2019640 colored.png" width="10%" alt="Хороший рейтинг"></p>
          <td>  
    </tr>   
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p><img src="images/book covers/6601071-oleg-kryshkin-nastolnaya-kniga-po-vnutrennemu-auditu-riski-i-biznes-processy.jpg" width="75%" alt="Настольная книга по внутреннему аудиту. Риски и бизнес-процессы" class="center-img"></p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p><a href="books/oleg-kryshkin-nastolnaya-kniga-po-vnutrennemu-auditu-riski-i-biznes-processy.html" target="_blank">Настольная книга по внутреннему аудиту. Риски и бизнес-процессы</p>
            <p><img src="images/noun_Online feedback_2019640 colored.png" width="10%" alt="Хороший рейтинг"></p> 
      </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p><img src="images/book covers/180407-dina-badmaeva-buhgalterskiy-uchet-v-selskom-hozyaystve.jpg" width="75%" alt="Бухгалтерский учет в сельском хозяйстве" class="center-img"></p> 
      </td>
      <td>          
        <p><a href="books/dina-badmaeva-buhgalterskiy-uchet-v-selskom-hozyaystve.html" target="_blank">Бухгалтерский учет в сельском хозяйстве</p>
        <p><img src="images/noun_Online feedback_2019640 colored.png" width="10%" alt="Хороший рейтинг"></p>
          </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p><img src="images/book covers/6525195-andrey-gartvich-populyarnaya-buhgalteriya-kak-ponyat-buhgalterskiy-uchet-6525195.jpg" width="75%" alt="Популярная бухгалтерия. Как понять бухгалтерский учет" class="center-img"></p>         
          </td>
      <td>
        <p><a href="books/andrey-gartvich-populyarnaya-buhgalteriya-kak-ponyat-buhgalterskiy-uchet.html" target="_blank">Популярная бухгалтерия. Как понять бухгалтерский учет</p>
        <p><img src="images/noun_Online feedback_2019640 colored.png" width="10%" alt="Хороший рейтинг"></p>
          </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p><img src="images/book covers/23465867-galina-lipskaya-recept-schastya-po-kitayski-kalendar-baczy-fenshuy-ci-men-dun-czya.jpg" width="75%" alt="Рецепт счастья по-китайски. Календарь. Бацзы. Феншуй. Ци Мен Дун Цзя" class="center-img"></p>
          </td>
      <td>
        <p><a href="books/galina-lipskaya-recept-schastya-po-kitayski-kalendar-baczy-fenshuy-ci-men-dun-czya.html" target="_blank">Рецепт счастья по-китайски. Календарь. Бацзы. Феншуй. Ци Мен Дун Цзя</p>
        <p><img src="images/noun_Online feedback_2019640 colored.png" width="10%" alt="Хороший рейтинг"></p>
          </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p><img src="images/book covers/21570365-e-potapova-9991157-buhgalterskiy-uchet-shpargalka-2-e-izdanie-21570365.jpg" width="75%" alt="Бухгалтерский учет. Шпаргалка. 2-е издание" class="center-img"></p>
        <p><>
          </td> 
      <td>
        <p><a href="books/e-potapova-buhgalterskiy-uchet-shpargalka-2-e-izdanie.html" target="_blank">Бухгалтерский учет. Шпаргалка. 2-е издание</p>
        <p><img src="images/noun_Online feedback_2019640 colored.png" width="10%" alt="Хороший рейтинг"></p>
          </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p><img src="images/book covers/19212758-andrey-gartvich-buhgalterskiy-uchet-v-1s-buhgalterii-8-3-19212758.jpg" width="75%" alt="Бухгалтерский учет в 1С:Бухгалтерии 8.3" class="center-img"></p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p><a href="https://www.litres.ru/andrey-gartvich/buhgalterskiy-uchet-v-1s-buhgalterii-8-3-19212758/?lfrom=283042441" target="_blank">Бухгалтерский учет в 1С:Бухгалтерии 8.3</p>
        <p><img src="images/noun_Online feedback_2019640 colored.png" width="10%" alt="Хороший рейтинг"></p>
          </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p><img src="images/book covers/11654736-alla-mercalova-5996826-uchet-i-operacionnaya-deyatelnost-v-kreditnyh-organizaciyah-kassovye-raschetnye-depozitnye-i-kreditnye.jpg" width="75%" alt="Учет и операционная деятельность в кредитных организациях: кассовые, расчетные, депозитные и кредитные операции" class="center-img"></p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p><a href="books/alla-mercalova-uchet-i-operacionnaya-deyatelnost-v-kreditnyh-organizaciyah-kassovye-raschetnye-depozitnye-i-kreditnye.html" target="_blank">Учет и операционная деятельность в кредитных организациях: кассовые, расчетные, депозитные и кредитные операции</p>
        <p><img src="images/noun_Online feedback_2019640 colored.png" width="10%" alt="Хороший рейтинг"></p>
          </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p><img src="images/book covers/3947245--.jpg" width="75%" alt="1С: Бухгалтерия 8.2. Понятный самоучитель для начинающих" class="center-img"></p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p><a href="books/--.html" target="_blank">1С: Бухгалтерия 8.2. Понятный самоучитель для начинающих</p>
        <p><img src="images/noun_Online feedback_2019640 colored.png" width="10%" alt="Хороший рейтинг"></p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p>Люди, которые ищут книги по бухучету, также могут интересоваться: </p>
            <p><a href="https://unive.com.ru" target="_blank">Здесь будет картинка</a> 
          </td>
          <td>
            <p></p>
          </td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
          <td>
            <p><h2 align="center">Остальные книги:</h2>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p></p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>  
      <td>
        <p><img src="images/book covers/51927433-uliya-tryaschenko-zakrytie-perioda-v-buhuchete-finansovyy-rezultat.jpg" width="75%" alt="Закрытие периода в бухучете. Финансовый результат" class="center-img"></p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p><a href="books/uliya-tryaschenko-zakrytie-perioda-v-buhuchete-finansovyy-rezultat.html" target="_blank">Закрытие периода в бухучете. Финансовый результат</p>
      </td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>
        <p><img src="images/book covers/39489100-v-i-ivanov-17642476-angliyskiy-yazyk-v-ekonomike-buhuchete-i-bankovsko-fin.jpg" width="75%" alt="Английский язык в экономике, бухучете и банковско-финансовой деятельности" class="center-img"></p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="books/v-i-ivanov-angliyskiy-yazyk-v-ekonomike-buhuchete-i-bankovsko-fin.html" target="_blank">Английский язык в экономике, бухучете и банковско-финансовой деятельности</p>
      </td> 
        </tr>  
      </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

**denis-shevchuk-buhuchet-nalogooblozhenie-upravlencheskiy-uchet-samouchitel.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Денис Шевчук. Бухучет, налогообложение, управленческий учет: самоучитель</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" type="text/css"/>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
      <li><a href="../index.html" target="_blank">Главная страница</a></li>
      <li><a href="../buhuchet.html" target="_blank">Бухучет</a></li>
      <li>Денис Шевчук. Бухучет, налогообложение, управленческий учет: самоучитель</li>
    </ul>       
      <p><img src="../images/book covers/178219-denis-shevchuk-buhuchet-nalogooblozhenie-upravlencheskiy-uchet-samouchitel.jpg" width=25% alt="Денис Шевчук. Бухучет, налогообложение, управленческий учет: самоучитель" class="center-img"></p>
    <h2>Описание книги</h2>
      <p>Пособие-самоучитель будет полезно как для начинающих изучать бухгалтерский учет, так и для опытных специалистов, а текже для студентов, аспирантов и преподавателей, финансовых директоров, владельцев бизнеса, предпринимателей, налоговых консультантов, а также будущим специалистам и всем интересующимся данной тематикой.</p>
      <p>Затрагиваются вопросы организации бухгалтерского и налогового учета на предприятии, налогообложение, оптимизация налогообложения (в т. ч. оффшоры), постановка управленческого учета, автоматизация бухгалтерского и налогового учета, вопросы эффективного трудоустройства (как найти работу), учет и операционныя техника в банках и др.</p> 
      <p>Автор книги имеет опыт преподавания различных дисциплин в ведущих ВУЗах Москвы (экономические и юридические), три высших образования (экономические и юридическое), более 50 публикаций (статьи и книги), опыт работы в банках, коммерческих и государственных структурах (в т. ч. на руководящих должностях), Заместитель генерального директора INTERFINANCE, Член Союза Юристов Москвы, Союза Журналистов России, Эксперт в области налогового плнирования, ипотеки, кредитования бизнеса.</p>      
      <p><a href="https://www.litres.ru/denis-shevchuk/buhuchet-nalogooblozhenie-upravlencheskiy-uchet-samouchitel/?lfrom=283042441" target="_blank">Купить книгу</a></p>
      <p><img src="../images/noun_Online feedback_2019640 colored.png" width=25% alt="Хороший рейтинг"></p> 
      <p>Люди, которые ищут книги по бухучету, также могут интересоваться: </p>
      <p><a href="https://unive.com.ru" target="_blank">Здесь будет картинка</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

**style.css:**

```
/* Style the list */
ul.breadcrumb {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #eee;
}
 
/* Display list items side by side */
ul.breadcrumb li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 18px;
}
 
/* Add a slash symbol (/) before/behind each list item */
ul.breadcrumb li+li:before {
  padding: 8px;
  color: black;
  content: "/\00a0";
}
 
/* Add a color to all links inside the list */
ul.breadcrumb li a {
  color: #0275d8;
  text-decoration: none;
}
 
/* Add a color on mouse-over */
ul.breadcrumb li a:hover {
  color: #01447e;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: because font size 24px is bigger size you have applied to yout <a> tag.

Answer (score 1):

It's because in buhuchet.html, you have an CSS in your HTML page that change the property of `a`, like his font-size

```
a:link { 
  font-size: 24px; /* Размер шрифта*/
  font-weight: none; /* Жирное начертание */
  color: red; /* Цвет ссылки */ 
}
```

And in denis-shevchuk-buhuchet-nalogooblozhenie-upravlencheskiy-uchet-samouchitel.html, you don't have a CSS part in the HTML page and in the CSS file you don't change property (font-size) from `a` (link)